# Stability Condition of Forward Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

I've been searching all over the internet, but cannot find an answer to the following question:

Given some ODE $y' = f(y, x)$ with initial condition $y(0) = 0$, where $f$ is some real function in two variables, what are the values of the STEP LENGTH, call it $h$, that will ensure stability of the numerical solution obtained by the forward Euler method? The values of $h$ that ensure stability obviously depend on $f$. Is there a simple formula of some sort involving $f$ that allows for (relatively) easy calculation of the values of $h$ for which the numerical solution is stable?

Note: Suppose the solution to the original problem is unique.

Comment: You may try to look at Atkinson's Introduction to Numerical Analysis.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2):

The stability region is a circle of radius $1$ around $-1$. This is usually one if the first examples if stability of RK methods is discussed. For practical purposes you should keep $Lh\le 1$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$. This does not guarantee stability, the shape of the circle does not allow such a claim, but should keep the result reasonable for an order 1 method.

Comment: The stability region is the circle of radius 1 around -1? What does this mean? Assuming h, the step length, is real and positive, h is not in the circle of radius 1 around -1.

Comment: Are you referring to the case when f(x, y) = ky for some k? In this case, the stability region is | 1 + kh | =< 1.

Comment: Yes, which means that $kh$ has to be in a circle of radius $1$ around $-1$. However, if you are computing with a number format with relative precision $\epsilon$, then a first rule of thumb is that $Lh\sim \sqrt{\epsilon}$, where $L$ is a Lipschitz constant of $f$, gives an optimal error of magnitude $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.